# Input value of seletizeInput not available after update in server = TRUE mode

Tags: r, shiny

After an updateSelecticeInput with server = TRUE it's input value is not available immediately compared to server = FALSE mode. Is there a way to get the selectizeValue after the update in the following running minimal example also in serverMode?

```
selectizeOnServer <- TRUE # Switch between TRUE and FALSE and click button to
# see different console outputs after first click on button

library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "navbar", 
  id = "navbar",
  tabPanel(
    "panel1", 
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("go", "Go")
    )
  ), 
  tabPanel(
    "panel2", 
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "selectize", 
        label = "selectize", 
        choices = NULL, 
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    ),

    mainPanel(textOutput("text"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$navbar ,{
    print(input$selectize) # "A" when server = TRUE, NULL when server = FALSE
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "selectize", choices = LETTERS, selected = "A", server = selectizeOnServer)
    updateNavbarPage(session, "navbar", "panel2")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does modifying your server to this give you the expected behavior?

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  updateSelectizeInput(session, "selectize", choices = LETTERS, server = selectizeOnServer)

  observeEvent(input$navbar ,{
    print(input$selectize) # "A" when server = TRUE, NULL when server = FALSE
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "selectize", choices = LETTERS,selected="E", server = selectizeOnServer)
    updateNavbarPage(session, "navbar", "panel2")
  })

}
```

Comment: hi, Florian, unfortunately the same issue remains